# ion-rangeSlider time formate issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ion-range-slider

**I am trying to get Current rangeSlider value (which is time) but it gives a huge number i-e to and from values are respectivly  :[1650478833060, 1650394800000]. Its not a unixTime formate i tried that; so can any one help me get rangeSlider Exect value. thankyou**

my code HTML

```
<input type="text" id="ion" name="example_name" value="" /></td>
<button type="button" onclick="getRangeValue();"class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 98%; ">Blanking</button>
```

Javascript code

```
$('#ion').ionRangeSlider({
    grid: true,
    type: 'double',
    min: moment("000000", "hhmmss").valueOf(),
    max: moment("235959", "hhmmss").valueOf(),
    force_edges: true,
    drag_interval: true,
    step: 60,
    min_interval: 60,
    prettify: function(num) {
        return moment(num).format('HH:mm:ss');
    }

});

function getRangeValue() {
    var slider = $("#ion").data("ionRangeSlider");

    // Get values
    var from = slider.result.from;
    var to = slider.result.to;

    console.log("values ", [to , from]);
    
}
```

my Output are
[1650478833060, 1650394800000]
i have tried serval ways like

```
    let seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
    let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);

    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;

    // ️ If you don't want to roll hours over, e.g. 24 to 00
    // ️ comment (or remove) the line below
    // commenting next line gets you `24:00:00` instead of `00:00:00`
    // or `36:15:31` instead of `12:15:31`, etc.
    hours = hours % 24;

    return `${padTo2Digits(hours)}:${padTo2Digits(minutes)}:${padTo2Digits(
    seconds,
  )}`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function

```
function getRangeValue() {
    var slider = $("#ion").data("ionRangeSlider");

    // Get values
    var from = slider.result.from;
    var to = slider.result.to;

    console.log("values ", [to , from]);
    
}
```

i consoled `slider.result` value and it had an prettify time value in it which is the excet time on slider. so final code was.

```
function getRangeValue() {
    var slider = $("#ion").data("ionRangeSlider");
    console.log("slider : ", slider);

    // Get values
    var from = slider.result.from_pretty;// changed here
    var to = slider.result.to;
    console.log("Now   ---- ", from);

}
```